How to Add SSL Certificate to Outdated CakePHP Website with Apple FileMaker Server?
I'm trying to update an outdated CakePHP website and add an SSL certificate. The website is integrated with an Apple FileMaker server. What steps should I follow to achieve this? Any specific considerations for the CakePHP and FileMaker integration?
Steps for Upgrading that I think would be the right approach:

Assess the Current Application
Code Review: Conduct a thorough review of the existing application to understand its structure, dependencies, and customizations.

Database Schema: Examine the database schema to document all tables, fields, and relationships.
2. Update Code to the Latest PHP Version
Compatibility Check: Ensure the existing code is compatible with the latest PHP version.
Refactor Code: Modify the code to address any deprecations or compatibility issues with the latest PHP version.

Update to the Latest CakePHP Version
Current Version Check: Your website's CakePHP version is 1.2.6, while the latest version is 4.0.
Version Changes: There are multiple CakePHP versions between 1.2.6 and 4.0 (1.3, 2.x, 3.x, 4.0). Each version introduces significant updates and changes, including:


Changes in directory structure.
Updated code syntax.
Enhanced and modified functions.

The website current PHP Compatibility: CakePHP 1.2.6 does not support PHP version 7.2 or later.
Feasibility: Upgrading both PHP and CakePHP to their latest versions is not feasible without a complete rewrite of the website is what I think.
So my question is would it be technically not possible to update the current version to the latest PHP and CakePHP versions without rebuilding the website from scratch because we only want to add and SSL certificate and build with a long-term plan a new website.

We have checked the possibility for this, and we have found that your websites CakePHP version is 1.2.6 and latest CakePHP version is 3.7.
=> We have also seen that there is a series of CakePHP versions like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.x, 3.x and latest version is 3.7, during this version updating there are many more updates and changes are added to the CakePHP framework like :


Many of the directory structures are changed in framework.
Many of the code syntax are updated.
Many of the functions of framework are updated.
=> Also we have seen that your websites CakePHP version is 1.2.6 which does not support the latest PHP version


CakePHP 1.2.6 was released more than fourteen years ago. Regardless of all other questions, it needs to be updated. Maybe the other problems will also get resolved by a more current version of CakePHP running on a more current PHP version. I highly doubt that 1.2.6 supports PHP 7 after all, as this was released nearly six years later

"The website is integrated with an Apple FileMaker server" - what does that even mean? Is this in any way related to the main problem?

For consideration - FileMaker Server has the FileMaker PHP API marked as deprecated. The FileMaker Data API (which can still be used via PHP) is the replacement. Is the code using the older FileMaker PHP API or the FileMaker Data API? If doing the rewrite I recommend the FileMaker Data API which is much easier to code for.

An SSL Certificate can be used independent to the underlying Web application as you can make the SSL connection terminate before it reaches the application. Then the traffic is still SSL until the endpoint and the application should work as-is.
Even the server must not support it when you put another server in front which supports SSL.
After you've changed the network setup and added SSL, you can still continue to think about how to upgrade the application, but as you already noticed, it will like take more time (just to think about) then to just have SSL that is a solved problem and a commodity.

How would you approach this step? I think this could work. Would it work with perhaps Cloudfare? What I mean is Cloud-Based SSL Solutions:
If I consider using a cloud-based SSL solution like Cloudflare. Cloudflare can provide SSL termination and proxy services, simplifying the process.
Using Cloudflare, you can enable SSL without significantly changing your existing server setup. Cloudflare will handle the SSL traffic and forward it to your application.

No idea nor interest about Cloudflar,e I'd just run a server in front that is capable, e.g. Traefik, Nginx, Apache HTTPD, ... etc.. It's perhaps worth to put the app and the outdated server into a container.

Thanks. That's an even better solution for this project. Thanks a lot!
